# Infinite one time pads, brute force multiple pads?

Tags: encryption, key-management, key-exchange, one-time-pad

So based on my understanding using the same key for encrypting 
two completely random plain texts when using an otp cipher will still retain  perfectly secret. This is based on the answers on this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/can-i-use-a-one-time-pad-key-twice-with-random-plaintext/2).

The answers to those questions also say that using that data couldn't then 
be used to encrypt more messages. 
My understanding is that if the messages have been transmitted securely using 
2-time pad cipher. This should be equal to handing them off at a physical location.

What I  am wondering is why not be able to send new one time pads?
If the message are perfectly secure an enemy wouldn't be able to determine 
what the secrets are?
How would you brute force crack the messages since they hold perfect secrecy?

Comment: lets say I use pad1 to encrypt two new pads pad2  and pad3.  
then using pad2 encrypt m1. I now longer use pad2 for any purpose
I then use pad3 for two new pads, pad4, 5. 
pad4 for encrypting m2. lets say I continue this pattern for indefinetly.
what I am trying to find is where somebody could break this pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply, it's exactly the same as a two-time pad with one extra step.

So, as you know the problem with re-using a one time pad is that it leaks information.

If we encrypt *m*<sub>*1*</sub> and *m*<sub>*2*</sub> with *pad*<sub>*1*</sub>, that gives us:

*m*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*1*</sub> = *c*<sub>*1*</sub>
and
*m*<sub>*2*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*1*</sub> = *c*<sub>*2*</sub>

So if we capture *c*<sub>*1*</sub> and *c*<sub>*2*</sub>, we can then:

*c*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *c*<sub>*2*</sub> to get *m*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *m*<sub>*2*</sub>

If however, we re-use *pad*<sub>*1*</sub> to transmit *pad*<sub>*2*</sub>, and then use *pad*<sub>*2*</sub> to encrypt *m*<sub>*2*</sub>, we get the following:

- *m*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*1*</sub> = *c*<sub>*1*</sub>
- *pad*<sub>*2*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*1*</sub> = *c*<sub>*2*</sub>
- *m*<sub>*2*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*2*</sub> = *c*<sub>*3*</sub>

So now, as long as I capture *c*<sub>*1*</sub>, *c*<sub>*2*</sub>, and *c*<sub>*3*</sub>, I can do the following:

*c*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *c*<sub>*2*</sub> = *m*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*2*</sub>

Which effectively gives me the ciphertext I would have if I had used *pad*<sub>*2*</sub> on *m*<sub>*1*</sub> directly. So now I effectively have the ciphertexts for:

*m*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*2*</sub> and *m*<sub>*2*</sub> `xor` *pad*<sub>*2*</sub>

Which when `xor'ed` then gives me:

*m*<sub>*1*</sub> `xor` *m*<sub>*2*</sub>

Voila.

Comment: lets say I use pad1 to encrypt two new pads pad2  and pad3.  
then using pad2 encrypt m1. I now longer use pad2 for any purpose
I then use pad3 for two new pads, pad4, 5. 
lets say I continue this pattern for indefinetly

Comment: @5hammer It's the same scenario, with *n* additional steps.  Eventually, if you send two non-random messages, you can always get back to the xor of those messages.  So, while you can make it harder, you've destroyed the security of the pad, and might as well use an easier, more secure mechanism.